# Test existence of files in shell

Tags: shell

I have a list of files and I would like to pipe to a command to test if each files exists

```
cat files.txt | command
```

Does it exist any command to do that ? Do I have to write a script ? Can you help me to write it ?

For example:

```
> cat files.txt
libs/cakephp/app_exp/views/elements/export-menu.ctp
libs/cron/prad_import.php
main/css/admin/remarketing-graph.css
main/images/dropd-arrow.png
main/includes/forms/export/export_menu.php
main/jquery/jquery/jquery.cookie.js
main/mvc/controllers/remarketing/prad_controller.php
main/mvc/controllers/remarketing/remarketing_controller.php
```

but some of this files doesn't exits, so I want to do

```
> cat files.txt | command
libs/cakephp/app_exp/views/elements/export-menu.ctp
main/css/admin/remarketing-graph.css
main/images/dropd-arrow.png
main/includes/forms/export/export_menu.php
main/jquery/jquery/jquery.cookie.js
```

that returns only the existing files

Comment: `cat files.txt | command` is better written as `command < files.txt` (or as `command file.txt` if `command` can take an input file as a command-line argument).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you really using `#!/bin/sh`? In what context? An old Unix env, or in modern, stripped-down env with minimal cmds?

Can you use `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/ksh`? That will make it easier.

But in any shell this should work

```
while read line ; do if [ -f "$line" ] ; then echo "$line" ; fi ; done < files.txt
```

This should allow for file/paths with spaces in them, but if other odd chars are embedded in the filenames then more work maybe required.

IHTH

Answer (score 1):

```
test -f "files.txt" && cat "files.txt" | command
```

Also

```
[[ -f "files.txt" ]] && cat "files.txt" | command  # in BASH
```

take your pick. `test` is more portable.

Understanding that you want `command` to test for file existence, then you do not need a pipe at all. You can do something like this with a `while` loop:

```
while read file; do
    if test -f "$file"; then
        echo "the file exists"  # or whatever you want to do
    else
        echo "the file does NOT exist"  # or whatever you want to do
    fi
done < "files.txt"
```

This will read the file line-by-line and test each file for existence. You can also read all filenames from files.txt into an array and then loop through the array if you prefer. And yes, the above can be a script.

Comment: In fact, I put `command` in my question, this is the command I am asking for. Do you suggest `cat files.txt | test -f` ?